# Sponsored tags no longer show appropriate icon

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, advertising, sponsored-tags

Sponsored tags no longer show appropriate icon next to tag name.

For instance, Android tag had green Android logo, that is no longer there:

[image]

While it is always possible that some tag is no longer sponsored, I checked several tags from various companies that used to have icon and neither one is showing the icon at the moment.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as only applicable to one specific site as tag sponsorship is a Stack Overflow-only feature.

Comment: Not really much point to closing this at all

Comment: @Sonic so you should close [all those questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sponsored-tags) and ask to blacklist the tag so people won't waste their time using it. I don't agree with it, but that's the proper course of action if you think those questions do not belong here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Looks like the "android" sponsorship ended on Dec 31 '19 at 23:59, along with 38 other tags. So, no icon until/unless they renew.

I see one active sponsorship on the first page of tags, so the system's still working:

[image: sql-server is still sponsored]

Comment: Let me guess...they were ten-year agreements beginning January 1, 2010?

Comment: Is it possible to know/find the numbers? How many tags were sponsored? And are these sponsorships a 1 year deal or something else? Or is it some private data like "*SO Inc. eyes only*"?

Comment: Not really public info. Agree it can be disconcerting when stuff disappears without notice, but so it goes.

Comment: @OldPadawan [here is an answer of mine](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328236/is-there-a-list-of-sponsored-tags/328278#328278) that could answer the first two questions. You have to run the code for yourself to get fresh data.

Comment: Thanks, I knew Google had a lot of them, so I went to check some MS ones and Sony... and they were also gone...  Too bad, those icons were also great visual helper when browsing front page.

Comment: @Sonic more likely SE asks for more money this year. But can't know for sure of course. Anyway, really no big deal.